# Discord.js in an Express RESTful API

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, express, discord.js

I am trying to use the [Discord.js](https://discord.js.org) library in an Express RESTful API. I'm wondering how I should share the client between controllers, because the client is initialized asynchronously and apparently it is bad practice to call `client.login(...)` multiple times. In other words, I have an asynchronous initialization method that I cannot call multiple times and I need to access this client across multiple controllers. Here's what I'm doing right now:

**`discord.helper.js`**

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');

const client = new Discord.Client();
client.login(process.env.DISCORD_BOT_TOKEN);

export default client;
```

My issue is that because the `client.login()` is asynchronous but can *only be called one time*, I cannot import this file with the assumption that the bot has already been initialized. Any ideas on how I should structure this module so that I can import it multiple times with the assumption that it has already been initialized?

Answer (score 1):

Client#login is asynchronous but it does not return a `Client` instance once resolved, [See here](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=login)

You can safely assume the client is available as long as it was able to login, however if possible I would make your Express server accept a instance of the client instead.

```js
import { createServer } from "./server"
import { Client } from "discord.js"

const client = new Client()
const app = startServer(client)

client.login(process.env.DISCORD_BOT_TOKEN)

app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log("Express server is listening on port 3000")
});
```

Example of `createServer`

```js
import express from "express"

export const createServer = client => {
  const app = express()

  app.get("/", (_, res) => {
    res.send(`${client.user.username} says hello`)
  })

  return app
}
```

Comment: Hmmm...this works, but not for more modular projects like mine. Also, this seems a bit hacky considering Discord.js is only used in one route.

Comment: My "modular" do you mean you are working in a monorepo? if that's the case it should be no problem to export the client instance like this

Comment: It's not a monorepo, no. However, I have routers that call controllers that call services that call models, and the models need access to the Discord.js client. It does not make sense to pass the client down through all those levels to the model layer.

Comment: You could also import the client instance in your models, when you import the client once it is logging in / initialized, after that it can be used anywhere after (it should not login again), try to add a ready event listener to your client and console log anything so you can be sure it's not logging in multiple times.